# Restriction on $\theta$ for cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

In my multi-varibale calculus textbook the following are stated as restrictions on $\theta$ for cylindrical coordinates to ensure that $\theta$ lies between $0$ and $2 \pi$ where $tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ is between $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$

if $x>0$ and $y \geq 0$, $\theta = tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ (this I understand)

if $x<0$, $\theta = \pi + tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

if $x>0, y<0$, $\theta = 2\pi + tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

Can someone explain these last two statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $(x, y)$ is in the second (upper-left) quadrant. Then $\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ will actually give us a negative angle; in fact, it'll give us the negative of the angle $\phi$ between $(x, y)$ and the negative $x$-axis. Then $\pi + \phi$ is the angle we're looking for. This is similar for the third quadrant. For the fourth quadrant, we have $x > 0, y < 0$, and so $\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ gives us a negative angle; this actually is the angle we're looking for, except it's in $(-\pi/2,0)$, so $2\pi$ is added in order to express this angle as a number in $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: I am still a little bit unclear. In the third quadrant $tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ is positive? Also $tan^{-1}$ is defined for $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ so how does this relate to negative angles.

Comment: Right, $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ would be positive in the third quadrant (since $y/x$ is positive); namely, something between $0$ and $\pi/2$. But in the third quadrant you want something between $\pi$ and $3\pi/2$, and adding $\pi$ does the trick.

Comment: And if $y/x < 0$ then $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ will be between $\pi/2$ and $0$. But the convention for polar coordinates is to have angles between $0$ and $2\pi$, so negative angles should be shifted up.

Comment: you mean $-\pi/2$ and $0$

Comment: Yes, my mistake.